# How to add autocomplete feature of javascript (html5 objects) to vim?

Tags: javascript, html, vim, autocomplete

I want to use vim as editor for javascript and I need autocompletion :)
For example:

```
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
//                  ^
//                  |
//                  +----- Here I should have list of `canvas` methods after pressing Tab (SuperTab plugin).
var grd = context.createLinearGradient(0, 100, 200, 0);
//               ^
//               |
//               +----- The same is here but for `context`.
grd.addColorStop(0, "#aabbcc");
// ^
// |
// +----- Again
grd.addColorStop(1, "#ccbbaa");
// ^
// |
// +----- And again... You've got a point :)
```

Also, I need information about parameters of these methods.

Is it possible to have all these things in vim?

As far as I understand, I should somehow connect a javascript parser that can provide such information with vim. This is possible for c++ via clang. Is there something similar for javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a turnkey solution: none of the available JavaScript syntax files come with HTML5 API support and I've never seen an alternative `javascriptcomplete.vim` that provide HTM5 API-related completion.

But, judging by the looks of the script, I think it's doable.